# Change swt dropdown list element order

Tags: java, swt, jface

I am new to SWT, and there is a project which demand me to change the order of element in a drop down list, the list contains data stocking in the database which is ordered by the order alphabet, while I would like to change the order of elements in the drop down list,can somebody tell me how the dropdown list obtain the data list from the database and how to change the order? Thank you very much.

Here comes the code of creating an object, and I would like to know how to change the order of the list. Thank you.

```
public final Object[] getElements(final Object inputElement) {
    if (inputElement != null) {
        if (inputElement instanceof Test) {
            return getTest((EngdynoRequest) engDynoRequest).toArray();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Please be more precise about the components you are using and if possible add SSCCE

Comment: I am using the controller to provide the list ordered which will be showed in a combo box. I think the object is already created. They have created a content provider to offer the list, and labelProvider to show all of the data in the combo box. And there is a function named Object[] getElements(), I thnik they use this to generate the list, I put the code below.

Answer (score 0):

make your own list of objects, after that you can order it in any way which you need, after that you can make your dropdown list with ordered elements.

Comment: I am using the controller to provide the list ordered which will be showed in a combo box. I think the object is already created. They have created a content provider to offer the list, and labelProvider to show all of the data in the combo box. And there is a function named Object[] getElements(), I thnik they use this to generate the list, I put the code below.

Answer (score 0):

If you have correctly located the method used for populating the combobox you can just sort the list of objects here.

```
return getTest((EngdynoRequest) engDynoRequest).toArray();
```

can be replaced with

```
Object[] unsorted = getTest((EngdynoRequest) engDynoRequest).toArray();
return Arrays.sort(unsorted);
```

If you want custom sorting order you can pass your own comparator via
[Arrays.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try with your method

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of methods on `ComboViewer` that you may want to look at

```
StructuredViewer.java

public void setComparer(IElementComparer comparer) 

public void setComparator(ViewerComparator comparator)

public void setSorter(ViewerSorter sorter)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might make it easier to understand:

```
      // Re-sort
      String[] items = combo.getItems();
      Arrays.sort(items);
      combo.setItems(items);
```